# "Can not find Symbol" error

Tags: java, gradle

I have a class `A`

```
class A {
  public static final String NO = "NO";
}
```

this class sit in `a.jar` in the classpath.

I have `class B extend A`. Inside `B` I am using the field `NO`.

While comiling class `B` with a gradle script sometimes I'm getting

```
can not find Symbol NO error.
```

Any idea why ?

Comment: Check [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please add an example source code of class `B` to your question. In what way do you use the `NO` field?

Comment: I'm using it inside a static method : String res = NO

Comment: NO is a static field. Use A.NO

Comment: why I do not get any error or warning about this assignment in my eclipse ?

Comment: and how this explain the (Sometimes) compilation error ?